# Transform Excel table into list skipping blank values

Tags: excel, list, filter, transform

Unfortunately I have not found a solution in the web - hope someone can help me with the following:

My **input** is an excel table like the following:

```
|         |   Jan   |  Feb    |  Mar    |  Apr    | 
| Topic 1 |   yes   |         |  yes    |         | 
| Topic 2 |         |  yes    |         |         | 
| Topic 3 |   yes   |         |         |  yes    | 
| Topic 4 |         |         |         |  yes    |
```

My desired **output** is a list where all blank elements are eliminated. It should look like this:

```
|         |   Jan   |  Feb    |  Mar    |  Apr    | 
|         | Topic 1 | Topic 2 | Topic 1 | Topic 3 | 
|         | Topic 3 |         |         | Topic 4 |
```

Anyone has a smart idea how to do this? I thought a second about a pivot table but was not able to do it.

PS: I can easily handle the intermediate step to replace `yes` in the input table with the respective `Topic *`, but I am not able to perform the second step of skipping the blanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a formula solution, assuming your data is in A1:E5, first copy the months into a new horizontal range, then, in the cell below `Jan`, enter the following formula as an **array-formula** by holding down `ctrl+shift` while hitting `enter`.  (If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula in the formula bar:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$5,SMALL((B$2:B$5="yes")*ROW($A$2:$A$5),ROWS($1:1)+COUNTBLANK(B$2:B$5))),"")
```

Adjust the cell references as appropriate, but keep the addressing methods as shown in the formula.

Then drag down and to the right.

Comment: It would be great if you could explain how that equation works. I have no idea how the small function solves this problem lol.

Comment: @steventaitinger I think if you use Excel's `Evaluate Formula` tool that will help.  The `SMALL` function `k` argument, when adjusted by the `COUNTBLANK` function, will return an appropriate non-empty row number depending on the position of the formula in the results table.

Answer (score 1):

If we start with:

[image]

We can first replace the "yes"s.  Then remove the blanks. Then clear the first column.  We run macro **MAIN**

```
Sub MAIN()
    Call step1
    Call step2
    Call step3
End Sub

Sub step1()
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If r.Value = "yes" Then
            r.Value = Cells(r.Row, 1).Value
        End If
    Next r
End Sub

Sub step2()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    r.Delete (xlShiftUp)
End Sub

Sub step3()
    Range("A:A").Clear
End Sub
```

to produce:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the macro solution - I really liked it and works great!

Answer (score 0):

Select the appropriate range, HOME > Editing, Find & Select, Go To Special..., Blanks, select one of those selected, Delete..., Shift cells up, OK.